# How to setup RAM disk for video editing?

Tags: memory, ramdisk

I am looking to utilize my RAM disk with **the goal of decreasing render times** and partly because it is to save on lifetime writes on my SSD and spare my hard drive from wear and tear due to constant rendering.

I have a system with 128GB DDR4, RTX 3080 Ti, Ryzen 9 5900X CPU and a Samsung 970 EVO NVMe SSD as my C:/ drive, all backed up on a UPS and I am using Camtasia as my video editing software. I have setup the software to use a folder in the ram disk as its cache folder and to output the rendered video files onto the ram disk.

Do I need to install the video editor onto the RAM disk itself? The premise being - The video editor itself access dependencies from C:\ drive, which causes a delay.

Comment: Video encoding is not generally limited by I/O, except when working with high-resolution uncompressed material. This will not speed up anything.

Comment: What else is it limited by? I can't think of any other limitation other than I/O but I am curious to know.

Comment: CPU power for encoding

Answer (score 1):

This video shows how do make sure that Camtasia is both setup for GPU acceleration, and that the correct GPU is selected.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fj9s2vFFLuU

Here under preferences:
[image: advanced preferences]
Is the first part.

Then you need to go into windows, and make sure your software is assigned to the correct GPU and not one integrated into some CPU.

### Please watch said video.

Addenum  ImDisk Toolkit has a utility for creating a RAM DISK.

Let me suggest something else because is RAM expensive and small.

Either directly add or get a PCIe card that allows you to add a NVMe drive to your computer.

A NVMe with pcie gen 3 can get 3000mb/s and a pcie 4.0 can get 6000mb/s and you can have a TB of it relatively cheap.  It would be rare that a video editing project would benefit from any more than that.

Comment: Thanks. Although this isn't a direct answer to my query, it is nonetheless a helpful suggestion.